# Map is omitting one curly braces

Tags: java, json

I have a json array which i am putting in a map.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++){

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                    Iterator<Object> keysItr = jsonobj.keys();
                    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
                        Object key = keysItr.next();
                        Object value = jsonobj.get((String) key);

                        map.put((String) key, value);

                    }
                System.out.println(map);
```

But when I display the map it gives me a string in which there is one curly brace missing.

Output

```
{
  subtype=text, 
  maxlength=22, 
  values=[
    {
      "label":"Time",
      "value":"two",
      "selected":true
    },{
      "label":"Milk",
      "value":"hot"
    },{
      "label":"sky",
      "value":"blue"
    }
  ],
  (HERE) 
  name=text-1496816623336, 
  description=sa, 
  className=form-control, 
  label=Text Field, 
  type=text, 
  required=true
}
```

I have used jackson and gson also but in that case they weren't even putting the whole json into map.It might be a stupid question but thanks.

EDIT :

Here is the JSON used to create the `Map`

```
[
  {
    "type":"select",
    "label":"Select",
    "className":"form-control‌​",
    "name":"select-149‌​6823185891",
    "values"‌​:[
      {
        "label":"Option 1",
        "value":"option-1",
        "selected":true
      },{
        "label":"Option 2",
        "value":"option-2"
      },{
        "label":"Option 3",
        "value":"option-3"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "type":"text",
    "label":"Text Field",
    "className":"form-control",
    "name":"text-1496823186970‌​",
    "subtype":"text"
  }
]
```

Comment: Calling `toString()` on a regular `java.util.HashMap` does *not* print valid JSON. You need to properly render it as JSON by using whatever JSON library you are using, not by simply calling `toString()` on the map.

Comment: Could you post the JSON used to populate the map ? They will match, not in syntax but in content. PS : adding some newline in the String would give you a better view on the format, nothing is wrong with it

Comment: @Jesper I have used jackson but it was giving me half not the complete json. Actually I want to pass this map to elastic for indexing.

Comment: @AxelH This json I am getting from jquery formbuilder and then I am storing it in a string

Comment: Now that I have edited the question to add the JSON you have posted below and formatted the map output (I didn't want to as it was an answer ... but it was necessary). Please explain what is the problem.

Comment: @AxelH In the output you will see i have written (HERE) . In that place a curly brace is missing. Actually I am sending this json as a map to elastic but elastic is taking only one part of json and I think the problem might be because of that curly brace. Sounds stupid right

Comment: you think that the map will store a JsonArray like that. See my answer about your problem of conversion, if it is not clear, let comment there. But there is no missing character because a map is not a structure that will store an array. The iteration won't work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what I thing is that you expect to still have two `JsonObject` in the `Map`. The problem is that you iterate the `JsonArray` to put every key/value in the same `Map`, that means you override the previous value with the last one.

```
--first item : 
map.put("type","select");
--seconds item: 
map.put("type","text");

-- result
map.get("type"); //"text"
```

A `Map` is flat, you can't have two values for two keys, you could create a collection of `Map` to store every value like a `List<Map>`, on each `JsonObject` to iterate, you create a new `Map` that you store in the list

Comment: Hey I think that solves my problem..but can you please give me an example on how to create collection of map because json will be unknown to me.

Comment: @SarthakNegi That has nothing to do about the json, you just need to create an instance of `Map` on each iteration of `jsonarr`, and add that instance to a `List<Map>`. That `List` will hold every `Map`. Not the best approch, but this will do it. If you don't get that, I suggest you to take a step back, because you don't get the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey nope there is no curly brace missing,.... format the output and you will see:

```
{
    subtype=text, maxlength=22, values=[
        {"label":"Time","value":"two","selected":true},
        {"label":"Milk","value":"hot"},
        {"label":"sky","value":"blue"}
    ],(HERE) 
    name=text-1496816623336, 
    description=sa, 
    className=form-control, 
    label=Text Field, 
    type=text, 
    required=true
}
```

Edit (answer to your comment):
This is a valid Json string:

`[{"type":"select","label":"select","className":"form-control‌​","name":"select-149‌​6823185891","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"option-1","selected":true},{"label":"Option 2","value":"option-2"},{"label":"Option 3","value":"option-3"}]},{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1496823186970‌​","subtype":"text"}]`.

Formated:

```
[
    {
        "type": "select",
        "label": "select",
        "className": "form-control‌​",
        "name": "select-149‌​6823185891",
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "Option 1",
                "value": "option-1",
                "selected": true
            },
            {
                "label": "Option 2",
                "value": "option-2"
            },
            {
                "label": "Option 3",
                "value": "option-3"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Text Field",
        "className": "form-control",
        "name": "text-1496823186970‌​",
        "subtype": "text"
    }
]
```

In your one there is some hidden chars between `"values"` and the `:`.

Comment: thanks for reply..but see the json which I am getting  [{"type":"select","label":"Select","className":"form-control","name":"select-1496823185891","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"option-1","selected":true},{"label":"Option 2","value":"option-2"},{"label":"Option 3","value":"option-3"}]},{"type":"text","label":"Text Field","className":"form-control","name":"text-1496823186970","subtype":"text"}]        ..This is the json which I want to convert into a map

Comment: @SarthakNegi the one you posted does not pass the online json parser on http://json.parser.online.fr/